# How do I use typescript definition files (.d.ts) in a angularjs application without reference path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, .d.ts

I want to use .d.ts files for intellisense in javascript using VScode. For example, I have an angular js file comments.js, In this file, I want to use the type definitions from utilities.d.ts which exports a namespace "Utilities".

So typing Utilties. would trigger intellisense for the methods in utilities.d.ts.

Is this possible in a javascript application without using reference path?
/// ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a separate folder for your typings and reference them in the *tsconfig.json* file:

```
{
    "include": [
        "src/typings/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
}
```

According to the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) you can also use the `compilerOptions/typeRoots` section, but I use `include` to reference my typings and it works fine.